# What function would be best to check if values from req.param are type of NaN and set some value if they are?

Tags: javascript, node.js

About page:
I've got a react app which sends the url params to the backend server. Now url from the frontend looks something like: `maxprice=100000&minsqm=50&maxsqm=100&page=1` and these are users filters for DB. Now on the backend I've created `const` to catch values and works fine.

Now if I want to filter these from DB, I need to send them to the sequelize and filter data. Now everything works fine until some parameter wasn't sent - if url looks like this: `maxprice=100000&minsqm=&maxsqm=&page=1`
note that `minsqm` `maxsqm` values are `NaN` (thats what I get when I `console.log`)

Now I've been creating multiple `if` statements where I check if there is data. Something like this

```
if (!maxPrice) {
    const maxPrice = 9999999;
    //then do the logic with DB...
```

So I was checking for `maxPrice` and if not I was setting some acceptable value. Issue is this that I need to make multiple 'if' statements to check every `req.query` individually and then do the DB logic.

Is there some easier way to implement this? Ideally, I would like to have some kind of function to do this logic: Check `req.query` constants. If they are `NaN`(not in req.query) set some default value, if not keep that value.

Any ideas? Thanks!

controller.js

```
  const page = parseInt(req.query.page);
  const maxPrice = parseInt(req.query.maxprice);
  const minSqm = parseInt(req.query.minsqm);
  const maxSqm = parseInt(req.query.maxsqm);

  function checkQueryParams () {
    //here i would like to check maxprice, minsqm, maxsqm
  }

  if (!maxPrice) {
    const maxPrice = 9999999;
    //DB logic...
  } else {
    //DB logic..
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach may be the way that you are looking for.

```js
function parseIntOrDefault(str, defaultValue) {
    const result = parseInt(str);
    return isNaN(result) ? defaultValue : result;
}

const page = parseIntOrDefault(req.query.page, 1);
const maxPrice = parseIntOrDefault(req.query.maxprice, 99999);
const minSqm = parseIntOrDefault(req.query.minsqm, 1);
const maxSqm = parseIntOrDefault(req.query.maxsqm, 9);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#short-circuit_evaluation) on the assignment:

```js
const page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 123;
const maxPrice = parseInt(req.query.maxprice) || 9999999;
const minSqm = parseInt(req.query.minsqm) || 1;
const maxSqm = parseInt(req.query.maxsqm) || 9;
```

Caution: If the value is Zero (which is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Glossary/Falsy)), the right-hand expression is evaluated!

---

If you want to check for `null` and `undefined` only, and you use NodeJS Version 14.0 and up, you could use [Nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) directly in the assignment:

```js
const page = parseInt(req.query.page) ?? 123;
const maxPrice = parseInt(req.query.maxprice) ?? 9999999;
const minSqm = parseInt(req.query.minsqm) ?? 1;
const maxSqm = parseInt(req.query.maxsqm) ?? 9;
```

This will not work for `NaN` tho.

Comment: I'm using v10.x. I will update it rn and check if it works

Comment: @NullDev `const page = parseInt(req.query.page) ?? "foo";` default string for int?

Comment: Doesn't [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=parseInt) return `NaN` and not `undefined`?

Answer (score 0):

This is propably not the best practice, but it will solve your problem i think

So you want to avoid "null" and to make sure it's a number
there is a quick and dirty way to do what you want

you can use the || operator on variables to give them a default value:

```js
const test = null || 9999;
console.log(test);
```

there is also another interesting thing in javascript, which transforms easly a string to a number, by just adding a + sign before the string. If it's not a valid number, it will be still a number type variable, but the content is NaN

```js
const test = +"999";
console.log(typeof test);
const test2 = +"string";
console.log(test2);
console.log(typeof test2);
```

so if we combine it now, the || operator will give you the 0 instead of the NaN

```js
const a = +"b" || 0;
const b = 99999 || 0;
const c = +"99999" || 0;
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```

so my answer is

```
const page = +req.query.page || 0;
const maxPrice = +req.query.maxprice || 0;
const minSqm = +req.query.minsqm || 0;
const maxSqm = +req.query.maxsqm || 0;
```

but again, it's not good practice